# Restrict service account to list/view only a single VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I have created a GCP project with multiple VPC say vpc-a, vpc-b, vpc-c.
I have created two service accounts - svc-acct-a and svc-acct-b

Requirement:
On execution of gcloud compute networks list

1. svc-acct-a should list only vpc-a
2. svc-acct-b should list vpc-a, vpc-b and vpc-c

What is the best way to achieve this? Please describe in details with the required commands or UI configurations.

I couldn't find a way to assign IAM roles at a VPC level.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add permission at the VPC level but only at the subnet level. In addition, IAM Condition doesn't support [VPC or Subnet resource types](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-resource-attributes) and it can't be an option.

Finally, the `list` method, if the account (service or user) has access to this API, the API content won't be filter according to the permission (valid for all the API call, not specifically for VPC/subnets): the full list will be returned.

Comment: I'm almost blocked on HA VPN implementation between my project and a project owned by a different party. HA VPN implementation ( Both the peers are Google HA VPN ) requires access to the peer VPN networking details. Unlike classic VPN where we simply need to provide the external IP of peer VPN. My peer VPN GCP project owner has denied my access to his VPC networking info. Also tried mentioning peer VPN as on-prem or non Google owned VPN in HA-VPN configuration. However this failed as my peer VPN external IP was owned by Google.